# KeyError when calling on dimension in NetCDF file

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf

My goal is to import a NetCDF file and pull out the underlying variables stored in it. I've been following this [guide](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/).

Here's my code so far:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

fileName = 'LES_cloud_fields.nc.cdf'
fdata = Dataset(fileName, 'r', format="NETCDF4")
print(fdata.dimensions)
print(fdata.variables['nz'][:])
fdata.close()
```

To which I get the error: `KeyError: 'nz'`

Any ideas, guides, or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you check if `nz` is in `fdata.variables`?

Comment: `fdata.variables` is a dictionary, `KeyError: 'nz'` simply tells you that `nz` is not in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem lies in a confusion between dimensions and variables. In (atmospheric) models like LES, it is quite common to see both a dimension and variable named `z` (or whatever the developers decided to use), but that is not always the case, and information on a dimension (the variable containing the actual height levels) can be named differently. Consider this minimal example:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

f = Dataset('file.nc', 'w')
dim_z = f.createDimension('z', 10)
var_z = f.createVariable('z', 'f4', ('z', ))
var_z[:] = np.arange(10)

print(f.dimensions)         # output: OrderedDict([('z', ....
print(f.variables['z'][:])  # output: [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  ...
```

Which is probably what you expect to happen: there is a dimension `z`, which is also available as a variable. But if the developers decided to do something like:

```
f = Dataset('file.nc', 'w')
dim_z = f.createDimension('z', 10)
var_z = f.createVariable('height', 'f4', ('z', ))
var_z[:] = np.arange(10)

print(f.dimensions)         # output: OrderedDict([('z', ....
print(f.variables['z'][:])  # output: KeyError: 'z'
```

The dimension is called `z`, but the values are stored in a variable named `height`, and the last line gives an error similar to yours.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! I was just getting variables and dimensions mixed up. I all makes sense now. Thanks!